# Checking element visibility using elementFromPoint() method

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to check to make sure an item is visible before I start working on it using the following function

```
isVisible: function (node, doc, x, y) {
    var el = doc.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    if (node === el) return true;
    else return false;
},
```

`x` and `y` are positions of the selected node and is calculated by

```
findPos: function (node) {
    var pos = new Object();
    pos.left = pos.top = 0;
    if (node.offsetParent) {
        do {
            pos.left += node.offsetLeft;
            pos.top += node.offsetTop;

        } while (node = node.offsetParent);
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Everything works fine. However, when I scroll the page down, the `isVisible` function is no longer returning the right value. This is caused by the position having changed but the find position function not returning the right value.

Is there a method to get the position of an element like the reverse of `elementFromPoint`? Or does anyone have another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding `window.scrollX` and `window.scrollY` to the `doc.elementFromPoint()` input parameters `x` and `y`

```
    isVisible: function (node, doc, x, y) 
     {
      var el = doc.elementFromPoint(x-window.scrollX, y-window.scrollY);
        if (node === el) return true;
          else return false;
     },
```

this seems to work fine

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote an `isVisible()` method that uses the `elementFromPoint()` method and should work in IE9+ to detect if an element is visible.

```
var isVisible = function(elem) {
  var w = window, d = document, height, rects, on_top;
  if(!elem || (elem && elem.nodeType !== 1) || !elem.getClientRects || !d.elementFromPoint || !d.querySelector || !elem.contains) {
    return false;
  }
  if (elem.offsetWidth === 0 || elem.offsetHeight === 0) {
    return false;
  }
  height = w.innerHeight ? w.innerHeight: d.documentElement.clientHeight;
  rects = elem.getClientRects();
  on_top = function(r, elem) {
    var x = (r.left + r.right)/2,
      y = (r.top + r.bottom)/2,
      elemFromPoint = d.elementFromPoint(x, y);
      return (elemFromPoint === elem || elem.contains(elemFromPoint));
  };
  for (var i = 0, l = rects.length; i < l; i++) {
    var r = rects[i],
      in_viewport = r.top > 0 ? r.top <= height : (r.bottom > 0 && r.bottom <= height);
    if (in_viewport && on_top(r, elem)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

You would call it like this: `isVisible(document.getElementById('at-follow'));`

Also, here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/gfranko/5313617) of it.

Comment: it works perfect for element that disapear on scroll in a div

Answer (score 0):

This library should be what you're looking for: https://github.com/cpatik/within-viewport/blob/master/withinViewport.js

Comment: I posted another that is free of jQuery

Comment: this looks like it could work but its too much code for what I need, I was able to fix my own code aboce. Thanks